# How to Recover a Customer Custom Attribute?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, custom-attributes

I've deleted a custom attribute on `Customer > Customer Attributes > Manage Customer Attributes` but I need it back.

Is it possible to recover it? The custom attribute are still on database?

Comment: How you deleted it ?

Comment: I've choose it on Manage Customer Attributes page and clicked on `delete attribute`

Comment: I have a backup `.sql` from yesterday with these informations. But I don't know how to change only one column

Comment: Look my answer below, you can also make a full restoration database with your backup.

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted it like this, is that you deleted it also from the database, you have more than to recreate it again. if you don't know how, use this code below.

**To add a custom attribute to customer:**

**/app/code/local/Your/Customattribute/sql/your_customattribute_setup/install-0.1.0.php**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$entityTypeId     = $setup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
$attributeSetId   = $setup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $setup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "customattribute",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Custom Attribute",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => "Custom Attribute"

        ));

        $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "customattribute");


$setup->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'customattribute',
    '999'  //sort_order
);

$used_in_forms=array();

$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
//$used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
//$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
//$used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
//$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
                ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
                ->setData("is_system", 0)
                ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
                ->setData("is_visible", 1)
                ->setData("sort_order", 100)
                ;
        $attribute->save();



$installer->endSetup();
```

**/app/code/local/Your/Customattribute/etc/config.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Your_Customattribute>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Your_Customattribute>
        </modules>
        <global>

            <resources>
                <Your_Customattribute_setup>
                    <setup>
                        <module>Your_Customattribute</module>
                        <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                    </setup>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_setup</use>
                    </connection>
                </Your_Customattribute_setup>
                <Your_Customattribute_write>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_write</use>
                    </connection>
                </Your_Customattribute_write>
                <Your_Customattribute_read>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_read</use>
                    </connection>
                </Your_Customattribute_read>
            </resources>
        </global>

    </config>
```

**app/etc/modules/Your_Customattribute.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Your_Customattribute>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Your_Customattribute>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

**To retrieve it use:**

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($custid);
$customer->getCustomattribute();
```